# Simple field of type double, set to filterable, search filters not working

Tags: .net, azure-cognitive-search

I have a search index. There are a few double type fields that are set to be filterable such as ListPrice, External_height etc.

[image]

Now when I try to filter on any of the double value columns, I am not getting any results, for eg.

[image]

Whereas I know there is data for the applied filter:

[image]

I'm not sure if this has to do with the configuration of the field or just that data.

Comment: Have you tried 
`
{
"search": "*",
"filter":"ListPrice eq 99.99"
}
`
in `Json query` view? I have tested with double type data and it's showing the result.

Comment: You're right, it works in the json view, but I am actually trying to send this through my .net web app and its failing there.

Comment: For eg if i try this query in the JSON view of the index:
TenantId eq 'a9569182-fe6e-4141-5cf0-08dbe5d93f28' and External_Height lt 14
i get result but when the same query string is sent in the Filters property of SearchOptions object i get no result

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in the search text being sent with the filters in .net web app. Once that was fixed results started coming in correctly.